# Bar Button Items Won't Connect To Exit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers - one main VC (ViewController) and this is segue'd to another VC via "Present Modally" (DetailViewController). The ViewController is embedded in Navigation Controller whereas the DetailViewController is not embedded in anything.

In my ViewController I added two functions:

```
@IBAction func cancelToVC(segue: UIStoryboard) {

}

@IBAction func saveDetails(segue: UIStoryboard) {

}
```

So now when I go to my DetailViewController I am hoping to connect two bar button items "Cancel" and "Done" to the exit button. But it doesn't even highlight to allow me to select it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the "triggered segues" "action outlet"? CTRL+drag from button to exit icon?

Comment: @DepartamentoB Yes I am...I'm CTRL+Dragging from each bar button item to the Exit icon but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should set up your IBAction func's like this:

```
@IBAction func cancelToVC(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { // Not UIStoryboard

}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness that is extremely silly of me...thanks so much!